# How does VMware ESXi differentiate thick-lazy and thick-eager vmdk

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm using ESXi 6.0.0, and come up with a question. How does ViClient/ESXi know if a thick vmdk is **lazy zeroed** or **eager zeroed**? I checked the .vmdk content(several hundred bytes) from command-line shell and cannot identify a field that describes such difference.

[image: vmdk content compare]

Answer (score 0):

I think the flag is not related to the disk image itself, rather it is a VM property.

After all, for the filesystem both files (lazy & eager zeroed) are absolutely the same; on the other hand, for the VM (and the disk management console) the two files should be treated differently.

Comment: Then i'd like to know where this information is stored(so that I can manually convert a eager one to a lazy one). I checked .vmx, of course it is not there.

Comment: The parameters should be named `EagerlyScrub`. You can't find any reference for it?

Comment: From `/vmfs/volumes` I execute ``find -name '*.vmx' | xargs grep -i eager`` but get nothing. Can you be explit what file holds that information?

Comment: I though it was in the vmx file, sorry...